# CSS align items to the end with wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-width container and I want to display a dynamic amount of same-sized items that should be aligned to the right side of the container.

[image]

When there are too many items, they should wrap into multiple lines. However, I want the bottom lines to fill completely and the top-most line with the remaining space.

[image]

I thought I could achieve this with flex layout (like `justify-content: flex-end;`), but I didn't succeed.

How (if possible) could I produce the desired placement with CSS rules?

HTML can be assumed to be very basic:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="item">N</div>
</div>
```

Note: all items have the same dimensions, I just didn't draw them accurately in the images.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible with CSS as it stands. Maybe with a pseudo-element but I'm doubtful.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://prnt.sc/10q23nc

Comment: You should reverse the order of items so the Nth element is first, then you can do what you're trying to do with flex.

Comment: @Linek you mean its possible to produce my requested positioning with **completely** reversed numbers? Because until now I only get a mix with reversed lines and left-to-right in-line items or reversed in-line-order but not reversed lines.

Comment: @grek40 Yes, if you reverse the order you can produce what you're looking for with a combination of flex reverse properties. I could possibly make it an answer and show you if you cannot figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SASS to generate the code that will switch the order of all the elements:

```
$n:100;
@for $i from 1 through $n {
 .container > div:nth-last-child(#{$i}) {order:#{$i}}
}
```

Example:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

/* generated with sass*/
.container > div:nth-last-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(4) {
  order: 4;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(5) {
  order: 5;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(6) {
  order: 6;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(7) {
  order: 7;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(8) {
  order: 8;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(9) {
  order: 9;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(10) {
  order: 10;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(11) {
  order: 11;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(12) {
  order: 12;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(13) {
  order: 13;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(14) {
  order: 14;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(15) {
  order: 15;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(16) {
  order: 16;
}

.container > div:nth-last-child(17) {
  order: 17;
}
/**/

/* irrelevant styles */
.container > div {
  width:80px;
  height:60px;
  margin:5px;
  color:#fff;
  background:red;
}
.container {
  counter-reset:num;
}
.container > div::before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I accept this since there is no ideal solution for an unknown number of items and for many practical purposes (including my own), an upper limit of relevant items can be assumed. Nice to see a CSS solution without any need for JS or HTML side changes.

Answer (score -3):

The key here is to use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`

Here is a live demo in codepen: https://codepen.io/lefanous/pen/eYBwaRz

*I will also link to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ which is a complete guide to flex-box in css.*

Comment: Looks like a starting point, but if you give the demo items individual numbers you will see that the elements start at the bottom line with wrap-reverse

Comment: This is wrong as the order changes to not something the OP wants.

Comment: Note I didn't downvote here and I'm actually considering to use this approach together with manually assigned order. Ofcourse this would only be a workaround if there is no actual solution with css only.

Comment: You can't use a manually assigned order with a dynamic number of items. You'd need JS for that.

Comment: My mistake for using the same label. I was too quick there. I will try to find a way to wrap the elements with the right order.